# Usage of FutureBuilder with setState

Tags: dart, flutter

How to use the `FutureBuilder` with `setState` properly? For example, when i create a stateful widget its starting to load data (FutureBuilder) and then i should update the list with new data, so i use setState, but its starting to loop for infinity (because i rebuild the widget again), any solutions?

```
class FeedListState extends State<FeedList> {

  Future<Null> updateList() async {
    await widget.feeds.update();
    setState(() {
      widget.items = widget.feeds.getList();
    });
    //widget.items = widget.feeds.getList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder<Null>(
      future: updateList(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else
              return new Scrollbar(
                child: new RefreshIndicator(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics:
                        const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), //Even if zero elements to update scroll
                    itemCount: widget.items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return FeedListItem(widget.items[index]);
                    },
                  ),
                  onRefresh: updateList,
                ),
              );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The whole point of using `FutureBuilder` is to **not** call `setState` ourselves.

Comment: i understand, but i want somehow keep adantage to update data (from internet) after first launch with FutureBuilder

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Indeed, it will loop into infinity because whenever `build` is called, `updateList` is also called and returns a brand new future.

You have to keep your `build` pure. It should just read and combine variables and properties, but never cause any side effects!

---

Another note: All fields of your `StatefulWidget` subclass must be final (`widget.items = ...` is bad). The state that changes must be stored in the `State` object.

In this case you can store the result (the data for the list) in the future itself, there is no need for a separate field. It's even dangerous to call `setState` from a future, because the future might complete after the disposal of the state, and it will throw an error.

Here is some update code that takes into account all of these things:

```
class FeedListState extends State<FeedList> {
  // no idea how you named your data class...
  Future<List<ItemData>> _listFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // initial load
    _listFuture = updateAndGetList();
  }

  void refreshList() {
    // reload
    setState(() {
      _listFuture = updateAndGetList();
    });
  }

  Future<List<ItemData>> updateAndGetList() async {
    await widget.feeds.update();

    // return the list here
    return widget.feeds.getList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder<List<ItemData>>(
      future: _listFuture,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ItemData>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return new Center(
            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          final items = snapshot.data ?? <ItemData>[]; // handle the case that data is null

          return new Scrollbar(
            child: new RefreshIndicator(
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), //Even if zero elements to update scroll
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return FeedListItem(items[index]);
                },
              ),
              onRefresh: refreshList,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty for your comment, u really helped me, especially for Stating variables in State class!

Comment: Great example. I have a small doubt though. What if we want to append the updated list with current list? The current example replaces all rows with fresh data, I want it to get appended with existing rows.

Comment: Maybe ask a new question. You would probably want to use a `Stream` or rx `Observable` instead of a `Future`, with a `StreamSink` or `Subject` to trigger the loading.

Comment: But what makes Futurebuilder keep firing unintentionally.? Because my futurebuilder is doing that.

Comment: A widget might be built several times, and this is why build() must be as thin as possible. InitState is the perfect place for initializations, specially handling database reads.

Answer (score 10):

Use can SchedulerBinding for using **setState()** inside Future Builders or Stream Builder,

```
 SchedulerBinding.instance
                .addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
              isServiceError = false;
              isDataFetched = true;
            }));
```

Comment: This still creates the infinite loop issue

Answer (score 2):

#### Screenshot (Null Safe):

[image]

---

#### Code:

You don't need `setState` while using `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  // Declare a variable.
  late final Future<int> _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = _calculate(); // Assign your Future to it. 
  }

  // This is your actual Future. 
  Future<int> _calculate() => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => 42);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<int>(
        future: _future, // Use your variable here (not the actual Future)
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) return Text('Value = ${snapshot.data!}');
          return Text('Loading...');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case your example is missing his need, he needs the Future's content to update, thus while you're correct, your example doesn't demonstrate why. Instead, if you modified your code to change Value = X (other than 42) it would be a useful example.

Comment: this code does not update the UI