# FutureBuilder vs initState in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to load some data from an SQLite database in my Flutter application and show the results in a `ListView`. I am currently using a `FutureBuilder` widget to fetch the data asynchronously from the database and then build the `ListView`.

However, if I want to do some operations on the data - e.g. modify some information and save it to database - and then show the updated data in the `ListView`, I think I have to store the data in a local variable first and then call the `setState()` method to make changes to the data and re-build the page.

Is there any other better/preferred way to achieve the same without using `FutureBuilder`?

Answer (score 5):

`initState` gets called when your widget gets initialised for the first time. There you do some initialisation operations.

I think you're right to use `FutureBuilder`, since your UI gets generated after fetching the data from the Database.

I would do one of the following:

- Keep using `FutureBuilder`, then when you edit the data make an `async` operation to update the database and after the database is updated call `setState` to reflect the changes on the UI.
- Use a `StreamBuilder`, which is similar to `FutureBuilder`, but instead of building only once, it rebuilds each time there's a change on the stream it's attached to. This way you just need to update the datasource and the widget will update itself with the new data.

Talking about the second solution, I cannot go any further since I've never implemented a `Stream` that would allow to do this (I've always used `StreamBuilder` it with `Firebase` streams).

The first solution allows you to update the displayed data without asking again for the entire data set to the database.

I might appreciate some feedback from others regarding the second solution, since I'm not sure about how `StreamBuilder` manages a change of data.

I'll let you know if I discover more!

Comment: thanks @magicleon94, after a lot of research I've adopted the solution 1 using FutureBuilder for now, but was curious if this is an efficient way. I still need to learn about StreamBuilder and Firebase. Will keep posted.

Comment: Well I think it's quite efficient. You transmit only what you need and refresh the UI locally, with all the optimisations Flutter does ;) Thank you in advance for any feedback about `StreamBuilder` :D

Comment: @RakeshK so you are updating the database and then getting the data once again from the database? I'm trying to solve this issue myself, but I just want to get the data once and then POST changes to the database. To POST and GET for each changes feels like a bad implementation?

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52021385/11252673

build() might be called several times - that's why this kind of initialization goes better on initState.