# How to add more data to Flutter ListView Builder via Provider without resetting the scroll position to top

Tags: listview, flutter, scroll, pagination, flutter-provider

I am building a Listview Builder in Flutter and populating the items via a provider which fetches the data from firestore in a paginated manner.

So the overall flow is -

1. Main Widget gets access to items via Provider that returns a Future.
2. Main Widget then creates a ListView Builder wrapped inside a FutureBuilder.
3. The provider uses a service to query Firestore and gets an initial set of items via a getter
4. The provider then calls getMoreItemsData() for getting the next set of items from the scroll listener 
   when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list.

The issue I am facing is that after calling getMoreItemsData() my widget scroll position gets reset to the first item, whereas I want it to keep it at the last item so that the user can continue scrolling. I think it is happening due to the notifyListeners() that gets called from getMoreItemsData() but I need it to refresh my list of items. Is there a way to do this without resetting the scroll position to the top of the list?

Here is the Main widget with steps 1 and 2:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final itemsData = Provider.of<itemsProvider>(context);

    List<item> items;
    ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: itemsData.items,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          return Center(
              child:
                  CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.red));
        } else {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            // return: show error widget
          }
          _scrollController
            ..addListener(
              () {
                double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
                double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
                double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30;
                if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= delta) {
                  itemsData.getMoreitemsData();
                }
              },
            );
          items = snapshot.data ?? [];
          return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
            Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            elevation: 4,
            child: Text(items[index].caption),
        // ...  Card defined with some items
             ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my provider snippet with steps 3 and 4

```
class ItemsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
    bool _getMoreData = false;

Future<List<Item>> get items async {
    _items = await Service.getItems();
    return _items;
  }

void getMoreItemsData() {
    _getMoreItems = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here is my service snippet:

```
class Service {
  static final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;
  static DocumentSnapshot lastDocument, firstDocument;
  static final _paginationNext = 3;
  static List<Item> _itemData = [];

static Future getItems(bool getMoreData) async {
    var dataFirestore;
    if (!getMoreData) {
      _itemData = [];
    }

    if (getMoreData) {
      dataFirestore = await firestoreInstance
          .collection("items")
          .orderBy("sell", descending: true)
          .startAfterDocument(lastDocument)
          .limit(_paginationNext)
          .getDocuments();
    } else {
      dataFirestore = await firestoreInstance
          .collection("items")
          .orderBy("sell", descending: true)
          .limit(_paginationNext)
          .getDocuments();
    }

    lastDocument =
        dataFirestore.documents[dataFirestore.documents.length - 1];
    dataFirestore.documents.forEach(
      (doc) {
        _itemData.add(Item.fromJson(doc.data));
      },
    );
    return _itemData;
  }
```

Here is a code snippet for Items model

```
class Item {
  String item;
  String sell;

  Item({
      @required this.item,
      @required this.sell,
    // More ...
     });

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return new Item(
      item: json['item'],
      sell: json['sell'],
      // More ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: First thing, you might not need to use FutureBuilder. Add a ```print("boo")``` in the beginning of ```build``` method, whenever there is an update from the Future, the widget gets rebuilt, that's the reason your scroll position is remaining on the top. One thing you can do is keep control of the ```scroll position``` and when the user reaches the end or almost the end, then make ```async``` db request and, them to the provider list and just to use the ```ListView```. If you require a loader then at the end of the list add a ```LoadingIndicator``` to show loading and remove it when you havedata

Comment: For more info, checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021205/usage-of-futurebuilder-with-setstate/52021385#52021385