# setState not causing UI to refresh

Tags: flutter, setstate

Using a stateful widget, I have this build function:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(MdiIcons.atom),
            Text("Message Channel")
          ],
        )
      ),

      body: compileWidget(context),

      bottomSheet: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: DefaultTextFormField(true, null, hintText: "Message ...", controller: messageField)
          ),

          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send),
              onPressed: onSendPressed
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

As you can see in the body, there is a `compileWidget` function defined as:

```
  FutureBuilder<Widget> compileWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: createWidget(context),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print("DONE loading widget ");
            return snapshot.data;
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator()
              ),
            );
          }
        }
    );
  }
```

In turn, the `createWidget` function looks like this:

```
List<Widget> bubbles;

  Future<Widget> createWidget(BuildContext context) async {
    await updateChatList();
    // when working, return listview w/ children of bubbles
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: ListView(
        children: this.bubbles,
      ),
    );
  }

// update chat list below

  Future<void> updateChatList({Message message}) async {
    if (this.bubbles != null) {
      if (message != null) {
        print("Pushing new notification into chat ...");
        this.bubbles.add(bubbleFrom(message));
      } else {
        print("Update called, but nothing to do");
      }
    } else {
      var initMessages = await Message.getMessagesBetween(this.widget.implicatedCnac.implicatedCid, this.widget.peerNac.peerCid);
      print("Loaded ${initMessages.length} messages between ${this.widget.implicatedCnac.implicatedCid} and ${this.widget.peerNac.peerCid}");
      // create init bubble list

      this.bubbles = initMessages.map((e) {
        print("Adding bubble $e");
        return bubbleFrom(e);
      }).toList();
      print("Done loading bubbles ...");
    }
  }
```

The chat bubbles populate the screen in good order. However, once a new message comes-in and is received by:

```
  StreamSubscription<Message> listener;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    this.listener = Utils.broadcaster.stream.stream.listen((message) async {
      print("{${this.widget.implicatedCnac.implicatedCid} <=> ${this.widget.peerNac.peerCid} streamer received possible message ...");
      if (this.widget.implicatedCnac.implicatedCid == message.implicatedCid && this.widget.peerNac.peerCid == message.peerCid) {
        print("Message meant for this screen!");
        await this.updateChatList(message: message);
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }
```

The "message meant for this screen!" prints, then within `updateChatList`, "Pushing new notification into chat ..." prints, implying that the bubble gets added to the array. Finally, setState is called, yet, the additional bubble doesn't get rendered. What might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the ListView has a `UniqueKey`:

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
Stream<Widget> messageStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // use RxDart to merge 2 streams into one stream
    this.messageStream = Rx.merge<Message>([Utils.broadcaster.stream.stream.where((message) => this.widget.implicatedCnac.implicatedCid == message.implicatedCid && this.widget.peerNac.peerCid == message.peerCid), this.initStream()]).map((message) {
      print("[MERGE] stream recv $message");
      this.widget.bubbles.add(bubbleFrom(message));

      // this line below to ensure that, as new items get added, the listview scrolls to the bottom
      this._scrollController = _scrollController.hasClients ? ScrollController(initialScrollOffset:  _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) : ScrollController();

      return ListView(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        controller: this._scrollController,
          keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 50),
          children: this.widget.bubbles,
      );
    });

  }
```

Note: As per Erfan's directions, the context is best handled with a StreamBuilder. As such, I changed to a StreamBuilder, thus reducing the amount of code needed

Comment: If somebody could explain why this worked, that would be great for the community

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me explain how `setState` works according to this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html).

Whenever you change the internal state of a `State` object, make the change in a function **that you pass to `setState`**. Calling `setState` notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this `State` object.

In your case, I would say it's just a convention. You can define a message object in your stateful class and update it inside the listener and your `setstate` like this:

```dart
setState(() { this.message = message; });
```

### Caution:

Before any changes, you need to check this question

[Usage of FutureBuilder with setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021205/usage-of-futurebuilder-with-setstate/59497833)

Because using `setstete` with `FutureBuilder` can make an infinite loop in `StatefulWidget` which reduces performance and flexibility. Probably, you should change your approach to design your screen because [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) automatically updates the state each time tries to fetch data.

#### Update:

There is a better solution for your problem. Because you are using a stream to read messages, you can use [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) instead of the listener and `FutureBuilder`. It brings less implementation and more reliability for services that provide a stream of data. Every time the `StreamBuilder` receives a message from the Stream, it will display whatever you want with the snapshot of data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the code, there is no infinite loop since I'm not calling setState anywhere inside the functions used by ``compileWidget``. I tried adding ``setState(() { this.message = message; });`` to the end of the broadcast message receiver, but it still doesn't work unless the navigator pushes a new screen entirely (which is wasteful of energy, of course)

Comment: Just in case, I'll try the method in the second link to see if it does the job

Comment: @ThomasBraun There is another choice for you that can be helpful. Use `StreamBuilder` instead of the listener and `FutureBuilder` using this link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: I switched to using a stream builder. The result is the same: the data gets added to the list, but the widget doesn't redraw

Comment: But using a StreamBuilder was better than a FutureBuilder in this context, so thanks for the suggestion. Allowed me to use fewer lines of code :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it @ThomasBraun. The `StreamBuilder` probably is a better choice for your situation, but I think you need to simplify your code to trace and find the bug. I updated my answer, and I'm looking forward to hearing from you about solving your problem completely.

Comment: This is overall really bizarre. Even when I remove the use of StreamBuilder/FutureBuilder and have the body of the scaffold compiled with a basic ListView, as the items come-in through the stream and push elements into the chat bubbles list, the state doesn't update until "Flutter hot reload" is called, OR, if I happen to open/close the keyboard. For the record, I am using Navigator.push to open this screen

Comment: When I open/close the keyboard, it re-calls build, which explains why it refreshes the element list. Maybe this has something to do with why the updating isn't occurring?

Comment: Strangely though, when a message gets received, the build function also gets called, but unlike opening/closing the keyboard, does not actually update the list view

Comment: More updates: When a message gets received, then I double-tap the list view, the message then appears. The same thing for when I send a message; I have to first double-tap the listview before seeing the bubble appear

Comment: When adding a FloatingActionButton that calls setState() when pressed, the build function gets called, but still, the visual updates don't show. When I double tap on the listview, then like before, I can then scroll to the bottom and see the new chat bubbles. Strange!

Comment: Okay! Turns out, I need to add a UniqueKey() to the ListView! Now, it works as expected