# Flutter FutureBuilder questions when getting network image

Tags: flutter

I'm displaying an image using `FutureBuilder`.
I tried using https://stackoverflow.com/a/52021385/7068790. But the image still not show.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Future<String?> _imageUrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _imageUrl = getImage();
  }

  Future<String?> getImage() async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
      return "https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/labour-day-2021-6753651837108920.9-l.png";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _imageUrl,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
            return Image.network(snapshot.data!.toString());
          return Container(color: Colors.orange,);
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getImage method doesn't do anything. It lacks a return statement and thus _imageUrl won't ever return a String and only return null.

If you see `Future<String?>` in your code you should ask yourself why you are using the `?`. If you would actually get a String Flutter wouldn't tell you to use `Future<String?>` but you could write `Future<String>`. That's the great thing about Flutter's new null-safety futures, it complains in a case like this if you are returning null.

So to fix your code you need to do:

```
 Future<String> getImage() async {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
      return "https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/labour-day-2021-6753651837108920.9-l.png";
    });
```