# Prevent ListView.Builder rebuild for a particular ListItem Change in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

I am querying data from sqflite database and using a futurebuilder for the purpose of showing a refreshing icon. Once the data is retrieved through snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done, I am calling a ListView.builder method to show the data. I also have an icon in each of the list item that is displayed. Upon click on the item, I am toggling a column value in the database. As I also need to toggle the icon in the ui upon each click. For this, after updating the database, I am calling setstate. This toggles the icon in the ui but because of setstate, the entire list of items is getting rebuilt. How can I avoid this?I only want the icon of that particular listitem to change. Is Provider the recommended way to go to achieve this?

```
  class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final _dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  
  
    Future<int> _toggleFavourite(int id, int value) async {
    return await _dbHelper.updateFavourite(id, value);- //toogles the column value in db
  }
  
  
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
   body: FutureBuilder(
              future: _dbHelper.queryAllRows(),//Get all rows from db
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  final _allRows = snapshot.data as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
                  _codes.clear();
                  _allRows.forEach((row) => _codes.add(Code.fromMap(row)));
                  
                   return SafeArea(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child:ListView.builder(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                  itemCount: _codes.length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                                                                 },
                                        child: Card(
                                         
                                            child: ListTile(
                                           
                                              title: Text(
                                                _codes[index].code,
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                softWrap: false,
                                              ),
                                            trailing: SizedBox(
                                                width: 100,
                                                child: Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    IconButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          _toggleFavourite(
                                                                  _codes[index]
                                                                      .id,
                                                                  _codes[index]
                                                                              .favourite ==
                                                                          1
                                                                      ? 0
                                                                      : 1)
                                                              .then(
                                                                  (affectedRows) {
                                                            if (affectedRows >
                                                                0) {
                                                              setState(() {});//Rebuilds all the listitems :(
                                                            }
                                                            
                                                          });
                                                        },
                                                        icon: Icon(
                                                          _codes[index]
                                                                      .favourite ==
                                                                  1
                                                              ? Icons.favorite
                                                              : Icons
                                                                  .favorite_border_outlined,
                                                          size: 35,
                                                        )),
                                                        
                                                        .........
```

Comment: If you want to prevent anything from rebuilding, you should use 'const' keyword. However, it will be much better if you share the code.

Comment: I doubt updating the only icon is possible!! What bothers you if it's rebuilding the complete list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate Widget for the `ListView` item, and have the database and toggle functionality in that new widget.

Also, It's always recommended by Flutter to use `const` keyword which will not rebuild again for the specific widget.

Edit:

Create separate `StatefulWidget` as you have to toggle functionality

Ex: Include `InkWell` entire block in new `StatefulWidget` widget, and have your implementation there

```
   InkWell(
          onTap: () {
                                                                                 
          },
     child: Card( 
          ///......
          )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you pls show the use of const for above particular code as I am confused where to put it. Also when you say to create sepearte widget, is it better to create a  stateful widget for ListItem instead of ListView?

Comment: @user24826: I edited the answer, please have a look. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: thanks, putting ListItem into separate stateful widget solved it.

Comment: @user24826: Could you accept and upvote the answer

Comment: Done. Also just wanted to add that I found the real answer to my actual problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021205/usage-of-futurebuilder-with-setstate/59497833. Basically I shouldn't load the future directly in Futurebuilder. This causes the reload each time. Instead the future should be loaded in the initstate. I changed my approach to this as creating separate widget for ListItem solved it temporarily as again I started getting same issue when doing some updates elsewhere.

Comment: I added blog link, which describe this issue

Comment: Now that is also not working for one of my operation. Basically in initstate I am loading data from db to a variable and in future builder i am giving the variable. But now when I delete an all items from the db and do setstate, it does not update the UI. Debugging shows that snapshot data is still taking the values got from variable assigned during initstate to the futurebuilder which has all the items.  :(. So how do I proceed. I want to achieve below things  Show loading indicator if retreving from db, else show data ,  Perform CRUD on item which should not update the whole UI

Comment: create separate method and add future initialization there, and call same method from initState() and elsewhere you required, then do setState() this should work